# CS50 Course - Volume -

Tags: c, memory, cs50, wmv

I would like to ask a question regarding a one lab task from CS 50's course - Introduction to CS. I do not like to consult my "homework" as I am trying to do everything on my own, but I would like to be honest - I hit a wall over here. My code compiles well and produces an expected outcome. The aim of this task is to create a short c program, that will open a wmv file, then copy a header to the output file, and then multiply each sample by provided factor. My program deals with all of these tasks - as far as I can test (I have even compared input and output files with Audacity). However, tests indicate that audio is not correctly altered compared to the provided factor and expected outcome. I am providing a prt of source code below. You can just indicate what I should be looking for, as honestly - I have no idea. For me - everything is just fine.

```
float factor = atof(argv[3]);

uint8_t HEADER [HEADER_SIZE]; //const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;
int16_t buffer;
int16_t* bufferp = &buffer;
fread(HEADER, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
fwrite(HEADER, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);

while(feof(input) == 0)
{
    fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input);
    if (*bufferp * factor >= MAX) //const int MAX = 32767; <<Prevents overflow>>
        {
            *bufferp = MAX;
        }
    else
        {
            *bufferp = *bufferp * factor;
        }
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
}

// Close files
fclose(input);
fclose(output);
return 0;
```

Thanks for all your help!

EDIT 30.01.2021
: Properly working version no. 1:

```
while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input) != 0)
{
    if (buffer * factor >= MAX) //This deals with integral overflow.
    {
        buffer = MAX;
    }
    else
    {
        buffer = buffer * factor;
    }
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
}
```

Comment: You are looping one time too many (and so writing one value too many), which is not exposed due to ignoring the return value from `fread`. Use `fread()` to control the loop not `feof()`, and please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Also, you must always check the status of i/o operations. It is useful to check the file sizes afterwards too, to see it is the expected size.

Comment: ...also did you open the files in binary mode (to prevent newline conversions)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your support @WeatherVane! Now I understand what I've got wrong. I've corrected my code, it passes tests. However, it may now be ideal (I still learn to make things more efficient). I am posting fread fwrite loop in the original post- if you have any suggestion how I could improve it feel free to drop them - I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I would write the loop as `while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input) == 1)`. Test the specific value that you need.